# Transaction Isolation READ UNCOMMITTED is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using hibernate for database connectivity. Now I need read uncommitted isolation of transaction but it is not working for me. Please anyone help me what is reasons, I have used this code :

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional( 
isolation =Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
 public addRank(){
//here i want to change status of rank corresponding rank id 1 so i called private mthoed addChangeStatus with id 1 
 addChangeStatus(1);
  //here i want to get rank with id and status true but i got null 
} 

private addChangeStatus( int rankId ){
  // first get rank entity from database using given id 
  Rank rank = dao.getRankById("query");
  //set status of rank true here
  rank.status(true);
}
```

in dao `getRankById` method

```
Query getRankById(String query){
  //get currentSession from session factory 
   getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is reason read uncommitted is not working . In xml file i have also configure transaction manager as

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Can any one help me how i can get update rank entity within same transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot test `READ_UNCOMMITTED` from the same transaction.

What you tried to test there is not working but for a different reason. If you were trying to retrieve using `EntityManager#find()` you'd get back the result from the **1st Level Cache** that is storing your not-yet-persisted change without a DB round-trip. 1st Level Cache is not working via Queries.

So:

1. If you wanted to store and read in the same transaction then you don't need `READ_UNCOMMITTED`. Just change your retrieval to either `EntityManger#find()` or `Session#load()` to fetch it from the 1st Level Cache
2. If indeed you need `READ_UNCOMMITTED` revise your test involving multiple transactions.

Comment: but i am using two ids from read rank rand id and user id so how can use find and load . Because i am get rank corresponding rank id and user id . I need all work one transaction.

Comment: Since you are using SessionFactory then it should be session.load(). You can use any of the load() overloaded versions: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load-java.lang.Class-java.io.Serializable-